# Javascript under-the-hood toString conversion

Tags: javascript, string, floating-point, addition

I have the following function:

```
function addChange(result, bill) {
  for (var i=0;i<result.length;i++) {
    if (result[i][0] === bill[0]) {
      result[i][1] = parseFloat(result[i][1]).toPrecision(2) + parseFloat(bill[1]).toPrecision(2);
      return result;
    }
  }
  result.push(bill);
  return result;
}
```

Which is called as following, for example:

```
result = [["QUARTER", 0.25],["DIME", 0.10]];
bill = ["QUARTER", 0.25];
addChange(result, bill);
```

The output to the above is:

```
[["QUARTER", "0.250.25"], ["DIME", 0.10]]
```

Why does javascript convert those floats into strings before making the addition? Or is there something else going on? How can I move past it and achieve what I want, i.e., for the above example:

```
[["QUARTER", 0.50], ["DIME", 0.10]]
```

Comment: Use `Math.round(parsedFloat*100)/100`

Comment: @Shashank is that how you would force javascript to handle any 2 decimal-precision float number accurately?

Comment: I would use whichever method is faster between using `toFixed`/`toPrecision` followed by a cast to Number type and the `Math.round` with multiplication and division. I haven't tested the performance so I'm not sure which method would be better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Problem is:

```
floatNumber.toPrecision(2)
```

This creates a string from your number. The `toPrecision`-function is used to create a *representation* of your number with a fixed number of digits.

Answer (score 4):

From the mdn documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Number/toPrecision

Returns

A string representing a Number object in fixed-point or exponential notation rounded to precision significant digits. See the discussion of rounding in the description of the Number.prototype.toFixed() method, which also applies to toPrecision().